# Local Notification every specific day of week

Tags: ios, notifications, swift2, ios9, uilocalnotification

I need to create a local notification for a specific time (example at 18.00) fired every working day of week (not Saturday and Sunday) but I can't find examples or tutorial. I want use  with swift2.1.  How can I create this notification? My problem is define the firedate correctly of the notification

Comment: You mean, you can't convert objective-c code to swift?

Comment: No Fahri, I don't know how to create the notification for each days except Saturday or Sunday. My problem is define the firedate correctly of the notification

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `NSDateComponents` to create the exact date for your local notification. Here is the example, how do we create local notification with exact fire date:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:now];//get the required calendar units

if (components.weekday>2) {
    components.weekOfYear+=1;//if already passed monday, make it next monday
}
components.weekday = 2;//Monday
components.hour = 11;
NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.alertBody = @"alert message";
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

In this piece of code, I set the fire date to every Monday 11 a.m, and set it repeat weekly using `repeatInterval` of local notification. Code maybe wrong, need to test, but I guess this gives you the basic idea, also I don't code in swift, so it's objective c. Hope this helps!