# Schedule local notification at specific day and hour

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nsdate, local

How can I schedule a local notification that fire every Wednesday and Saturday at noon local device time?

```
let localNoonSatNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNoonSatNotification.userInfo = ["uid":"noonBreak"]
    localNoonSatNotification.alertAction = "Noon Break"
    localNoonSatNotification.alertBody = "Time for a break! Come and play few levels"
    localNoonSatNotification.fireDate = // get next Wednesday/Saturday 12:00 PM
    localNoonSatNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNoonSatNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNoonSatNotification)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local Notification every specific day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35101186/local-notification-every-specific-day-of-week)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone still needs help with this question [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)

```
// Configure the recurring date.
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
dateComponents.calendar = Calendar.current

dateComponents.weekday = 3  // Tuesday
dateComponents.hour = 14    // 14:00 hours

// Create the trigger as a repeating event.    
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(
dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set repeat interval,

```
 notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday
```

Hope this will help :)